# How do i include the Python(3.6) Coinbase API CB-VERSION header

Tags: python-3.x, http-headers, coinbase-api

As mentioned in the title I am using python v3.6

I'm trying to create a python application using the coinbase API and for my code I have:

```
import coinbase
coinbase = coinbase.Coinbase.with_api_key('key','key')   #Replacing the 'key's with my associated keys
```

and when I try to make the function call:

```
coinbase.get_user()
```

I get the error:

> coinbase.error.CoinbaseAPIException: ('Status Code 404', 404, '{"errors":[{"id":"not_found","message":"Not found"}],"warnings":[{"id":"missing_version","message":"Please supply API version (YYYY-MM-DD) as CB-VERSION header","url":"https://developers.coinbase.com/api#versioning"}]}')

I went to the aforementioned web site and found out about the CB-VERSION header and I have no idea how to implement this, every single way I've tried has failed and led to me getting the same error message.

Comment: Which version of the `coinbase` package are you importing?

Comment: Im using the coinbase API v2

Comment: Which version of the package please?  Where did you get it?

Comment: Do you mean the 2017-09-07 version? If not, i'm not sure what you mean by the package version. I got it from github https://github.com/resy/coinbase_python3/ and manually installed it since pip was giving me errors when i tried to run    
    pip3 install coinbase

Answer (score 1):

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client

client = Client(
    <api_key>,
    <api_secret>,
    api_version='2017-11-28')
```

That should work

Comment: It's not working for me. When I set the client with keys between  angular brackets, I get the error "Invalid syntax". If I don't use the brackets, I get error "mykeyname" is not defined. I use Python 3.6 and latest coinbase version (2.0.6). I have requests v2.18.4, pycrypto 2.6.1, six v1.11.0

Comment: I found how to run it. The correct syntax is client = Client(api_key='xyz', api_secret='uvw',api_version='2018-01-13')

Comment: The angular brackets aren't to be taken literally. That example was pulled from the built-in documentation. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using an unofficial, unmaintained, out-of-date and incompatible `coinbase` package.  The latest commit was three years ago:

- https://github.com/resy/coinbase_python3/commits/master

You'll need to get on board with a newer API, such as the official one:

- https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-python

Comment: When I try to install via pip3 install coinbase i get the error C:\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
even though i have the windows folder where that file is located in my path. Do you have any experience with  this issue?

Comment: No.  You might want to post a new question about that if you can't resolve it.  It has nothing to do with your original question.